# How do I add elements to an info.plist array?

Tags: ios, arrays, string, info.plist

I have created an `array` in my `info.plist` and now I would like to add a few `elements` to it. Thought it was as easy as adding a `string` property and drag it into the `array` but nope. I have even tried adding it to the `source` like this, but then it complained that the structure of the `source` wasn't ok:

```
<key>myArray</key>
    <array>
        <key>myString</key>
        <string>myValue</string>
    <array/>
```

How do I get the right structure in the `source` or how do I create a new `element` in the property list?

Comment: An array doesn't have a `key`. It just has a repeated element, in this case `string`  Key:value is a dictionary.

Comment: Ok, but it I create an array in info.plist and go to source, the name of the array is tagged with <key></key>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In info.plist file, If you want to input an array, the right format for that is:

```
<key>Key name</key>
    <array>
        <string>some value</string>
        <string>some value</string>
        <string>some value</string>
        <string>some value</string>
        <string>some value</string>
    </array>
```